# How would I write multiple lines of text to a file all at once?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io, multiline, streamwriter

I need to write lots of text to a file at once, but It has to be formatted in a specific way and not all in one line.

The code I have is:

```
  If System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filepath)
            sLine = reader.ReadToEnd
        End Using

        Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filepath)
            writer.Write("[HealthBarSettings]
            MaxHealthTicks = 50
            MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100
            DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50
            DefaultHealthPerTick = 200
            DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000

            TickAlpha = 200
            MicroTickAlpha = 140
            MicroTickHeight = 0.5
            MegaTickAlpha = 255
            TickThickness = 1.0
            MicroTickThickness = 1.0
            MegaTickThickness = 2.0

            UseCompression = 1
            GoTransparent = 1

            [GeneralDataHero]()
            FadeTimerForHealthBar = 2.0
            ZeroHealthAlpha = 225
            FullHealthAlpha = 200
            DefaultChampionCollisionRadius = 65.0")

        End Using
        MsgBox("File Written")
    Else
        MsgBox("File does not exist")
    End If
```

But that doesn't work because it won't use all of the text and just use the 
"[HealthBarSettings]" and automatically end the quote after that.

Comment: I prefer to create a stringBuilder object...append all values to it and then feed that stringbuilder object to writer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write mutiple lines to a text file using Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903938/write-mutiple-lines-to-a-text-file-using-visual-basic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB.NET does not support multi-line string literals. You have to indicate the line breaks yourself manually.

For example:

```
If System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
    Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filepath)
        sLine = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Using

    Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filepath)
        writer.Write("[HealthBarSettings]" & vbNewLine & _
        "MaxHealthTicks = 50" & vbNewLine & _
        "MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100" & vbNewLine & _
        "DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50" & vbNewLine & _
        "DefaultHealthPerTick = 200" & vbNewLine & _
        "DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000" & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & _
        "TickAlpha = 200" & vbNewLine & _
        "MicroTickAlpha = 140" & vbNewLine & _
        "MicroTickHeight = 0.5" & vbNewLine & _
        "MegaTickAlpha = 255" & vbNewLine & _
        "TickThickness = 1.0" & vbNewLine & _
        "MicroTickThickness = 1.0" & vbNewLine & _
        "MegaTickThickness = 2.0" & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & _
        "UseCompression = 1" & vbNewLine & _
        "GoTransparent = 1" & vbNewLine & _

        ' etc...

    End Using
    MsgBox("File Written")
Else
    MsgBox("File does not exist")
End If
```

It's much easier to do and looks a lot more sensible if you're building the string up dynamically with user preference values stored in variables, rather than hard-coding it all.

Comment: I did what you said and it all worked except this one line:
`            Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(filepath)
                writer.Write("[HealthBarSettings]" & vbNewLine &  _
"MaxHealthTicks = 50" & vbNewLine &  _
"MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100" & vbNewLine &  _
"DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50" & vbNewLine &  _
"DefaultHealthPerTick = 200" & vbNewLine &  _
"DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000" & vbNewLine &  _
 & vbNewLine &  _ ect... `
But at the start of the last line I get "Expression Expected"

Answer (score 0):

Put all your text (lines) in one array and use

```
        var arr = new[]{ "MaxHealthTicks = 50","MaxHealthMicroTicks = 100","DefaultHealthPerMicroTick = 50",
        "DefaultHealthPerTick = 200", "DefaultHealthPerMegaTick = 1000"};

        File.WriteAllLines(@"c:/temp/test.txt", arr);
```

It will write all your text lines in new line with proper formatting.
[image: Text in file]

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do this with a string builder

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder
sb.appendLine("Line1")
sb.appendLine("Line2")
File.writeAllLines(filePath, sb.toString())
```

This is a good way to do it because the string builder object is more efficient than concatenating a string repeatedly, details given [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/08/29/string-concatenation-vs-string-builder-_2d00_-the-performance-hit_2100_-see-it-to-believe-it-_3a00_o_2900_.aspx)

Comment: Not necessarily. You'd have to time it to be absolutely sure, but I'm skeptical of whether StringBulder would have a performance advantage here. You're not building up the string in a loop, so this can be pretty well optimized. Blindly following rules is not a good way to write optimized code. There are lots of scenarios where StringBuilder will produce *slower* code than the alternatives, although I can't be sure this is one without testing it.

Comment: That's a good point, I've read in a lot of places that stringbuilder is faster when it's more than 3 appends, but I'm not sure how .NET handles this situation since it's just one line of code essentially

Answer (score 0):

Cody Gray mentioned it very clearly, so i'm not sure how you managed to get an error on the last line.

Remember that all you are doing is really making a long string to save. You could write the whole thing on a single line if you wanted.

vbnewline adds a newline (clear), the & sign ready's it do add another line, and the underscore you see is used to allow the code* to be displayed on multiple lines (Optional).

The final bit of code for the writer should be.

```
..."[GeneralDataHero]()" & vbNewLine & _
"FadeTimerForHealthBar = 2.0" & vbNewLine & _
"ZeroHealthAlpha = 225" & vbNewLine & _
"FullHealthAlpha = 200" & vbnewline & _
"DefaultChampionCollisionRadius = 65.0")

End Using
```

The expression expected error you are getting sounds like you have ended with the & symbol, or underline character. It should end as seen above, with the last string value in "quotes" and a closing bracket.

When beginning vb.net i found it easier to add everything together into a single string, then put the string into the writer. Waste of time in the end, but can be put together a little clearer using string = string & value.

Comment: Yeah, you need that closing parenthesis. Guess I should have typed the rest of the code, too. I felt lazy and thought it was obvious.

Comment: It was obvious. If you made it any clearer than it would have been easier to just copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

On similar note if you want to save a multiline text in a textbox into a file use the following code:

```
    Dim iText As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Test.txt", True)

    For Each iLineTxt As String In Textbox1.Lines
        iText.WriteLine(iLineTxt)
    Next

    iText.Close()
```