# VB.net How to save a few Textbox text into a text files

Tags: vb.net

i want to save a few textbox into a text file
[See Picture](http://prntscr.com/568pib)
Can I combine text from the textbox and save it ?

Comment: You should be able to just concatenate the text into a variable and save it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't know the code for create a text files !

Comment: Check this MSDN tutorial: [How to: Write Text to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write mutiple lines to a text file using Visual Basic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903938/write-mutiple-lines-to-a-text-file-using-visual-basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sample code provided below

```
Dim filepath As String = IO.Path.Combine("D:\", "somefile.txt") 'Some file path

 Using sw As New StreamWriter(filepath)
       sw.Write(TextBox1.Text)
       sw.WriteLine(" " & TextBox2.Text)
       sw.Write(TextBox3.Text)
       sw.WriteLine(" " & TextBox4.Text)
       '
       'and so on
       '
  End Using
```