# How to open a notepad file from vb.net without saving it in local?

Tags: wpf, vb.net-2010

I have a some text in textbox. I need to open the text in notepad to view but i cannot save it in anywhere in my system.

Comment: What is the point to open it in Notepad?

Comment: i have a text box and a submit button. If i click a submit button the data in the textbox opens it in a notepad the main condition is the notepad file cannot be saved in any place

Comment: Yes you already said that. But WHY do you want to open it in notepad? What will the user do with the text in the notepad? Why having the text in the textbox is not enough?

Comment: i need to generate a report type in notepad so only

Comment: You don't answers the questions.

Comment: You must open notepad, wait for it to have started, then copy and paste text into it. This can be done sending keystrokes.

Comment: What will the user do with the notepad? Print it? Save it somewhere? Or just read it?
If the last one, why don't just make the textbox multiline and get rid of the notepad part?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible in vb.net you need to save the text file somewhere in your local machine....

For saving the text file you can go through this SO link:
[VB.net How to save a few Textbox text into a text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930386/vb-net-how-to-save-a-few-textbox-text-into-a-text-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
         Process.Start("notepad")
         Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
         AppActivate("notepad")
         SendKeys.SendWait(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Hope that will be useful to you :)**

Comment: @Nikil , Ok, i modified my answer it should work, you can see it in this [clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojjnebkli5i95zy/Clip_3.mp4?dl=0).

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier , You're right, but i think i'v solved it, see it in my comment above (the clip)

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily Yeah maybe, but he has to give proper information on WHAT is going wrong, maybe the notepad is not opening, maybe it has an error, ... we don't know.